# How to keep my ideas safe?

Tags: discussion

I want to share my ideas on this site (my problems in number theory),
and I don't want it to be stolen. In fact, I want to get a comment for my work, but I'm afraid it would be stolen.
Any help? recommendations?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @tomerg: Why would it get stolen? Anyway, if you post it you can always refer to this topic to prove you're the first one to come up with this (if that is the case).

Comment: Somehow my last comment disappeared... You might want to look at [this thread](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/951/copyrights-at-mo/) on meta.MO and also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/what-happens-to-the-questions-solutions-written-on-math-se).

Comment: Your name's on it if you post it here; I don't understand the fuss. @Theo: probably a race condition; I was the last one to vote for migration, and you were apparently posting your comment at the same time.

Comment: @J. M.: I don't think so. I posted it before I cast the second vote to close on the main site.

Comment: You wouldn't have control over whether someone else is motivated to go further than you in solving problems you pose publicly.  That really has nothing to do with this site in particular.  If others get ideas from you, then they would have the responsibility to cite sources, but they would have the right to go forward with their own work inspired by the ideas.  You may be interested in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22725/how-to-know-if-somebody-else-is-also-working-on-your-problem/22747#22747, an answer suggesting posting on MathOverflow to ask what is known about a problem, with comments.

Comment: If you have any ideas worth stealing, then publish them. Does that address your worry?

Answer (score 9):

If you are really, really worried about establishing priority: send the results in a sealed envelope to be deposited in the French Academy of Sciences, before posting your question here. (See [Article 5 of the mission of the Academie des Sciences](http://www.academie-sciences.fr/index_gb.htm).)

But seriously, read the comments and the links posted in the comments. And if you are not satisfied with how things work here, maybe you should reconsider posting those thoughts on this website.